# Reading a deep level xml tag with C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I need some help using Linq to xml, I've been reading online articles but still no luck, can anyone please help me out?

I just need to read an xml file, the problem I'm having is that it has lots of sub levels and I haven't been able to access them.

```
<Dias>
  <Dia id="0">
     <Restricciones>
        <Restriccion tipo="Ambiental" horaInicio="6" horaFin="10">
            <Placas>
               <Placa>4</Placa>
            </Placas>
         </Restriccion>
      </Restricciones>
   </Dia>
</Dias>
```

My current code is:

```
var dia = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;

var xElement = XElement.Load("Bogota.xml");

var d = (from dias in xElement.Descendants("Dia")
where dias.Attribute("id").Value == dia.ToString()
select dias).First();

var rest = (from r in d.Descendants("Restricciones")
select r);
```

But I've tried several variations, but no luck so far

Can someone help?

Comment: What do you want to come out? Please edit your questions to indicate that.

Comment: whcih element value you are trying to access ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
var d = (from s in myXel.Descendants("Dia") 
                 where s.Attribute("id").Value == dia.ToString()
             select s).FirstOrDefault();

var rest = d.Descendants("Restriccion").ToList();
```

Comment: I think I tried that with no result, but now it worked... thanks a lot.